# Identification of this set with red, white, and blue bricks (mostly)

Tags: set-identification

Consider:

[image: Red, White, and Blue (mostly)]

What set do these pieces go to? There is a [minifigure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_minifigure) that looks like it might be space-related.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This appears to be [60079-1 Training Jet Transporter](https://brickset.com/sets/60079-1/Training-Jet-Transporter).
[image: Lego set]

I found this by searching for [6096487: BRICK 4 X 6 W/BOW, INVERTED](https://brickset.com/parts/6096487/brick-4-x-6-w-bow-inverted) and looking at sets that included this part and some of the other parts visible in the bag.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. If this is a correct answer, you can thank me by upvoting and accepting the answer.